# twitter4j search by location returns nothing

Tags: search, twitter, location, twitter4j, tweets

I am trying to search tweets using twitter4j by longitude and latitude as follows:

```
    GeoLocation gl = new GeoLocation(39.8,-95.583068847656);

    query.setGeoCode(gl, 2500, Unit.valueOf("km"));
```

This location is supposed to be San Francisco. However, twitter4j is returning no tweets when trying to search by location.

Comment: P.S. I also tried to search by this:  query.setGeoCode(gl, 2500, Query.KILOMETERS);   Still, no results.

Comment: And your fully code? I just search with those parameters and got many tweets